# Can randomness be random?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-science, metaphysics, philosophy-of-mathematics, ontology

In mathematics, a true random number generator it's impossible, because any formula defines a process that, however complex, is not random.

A random event must be unrelated to any cause or condition, and therefore cannot be causal. It is a brute fact par excellence.

If I draw up a list of all the possible conditions, I can say that a random event is outside of it. But isn't this a rule that determines the conditions of a random event?

---

**Edit:** this question was wrong, I was confusing 'causal' with 'deterministic'.

Comment: Random means unpredictable. There are uncountably many TRNGs. So, knowing that RNG is TRNG does not tell you much about given RNG. And, well, since there are uncountably many RNGs you hardly can draw a list of all possible events. And you can't distinguish between PRNG and TRNG in countable amount of time.

Comment: @rus9384 Thank you! If random means unpredictable, it is an intrinsically relative concept?

Comment: According to current Computer Science theory it is unpredictable for any Turing Machine. Zeno Machine, for example, could predict something a Turing Machine can't. But, well, as there is no largest cardinal, there is no RNG that is not predictable for all machines. RNG that is not predictable for a machine A must be implemented on a machine B which is strictly more powerful than A. So, yes, from the position of modern CS it is relative. There might be people who disagree with this definition of RNG, though.

Comment: I suspect that most uses of 'random' do not mean random but 'unpredictable'. A truly random event would be inconsistent with a law governed universe. Hence the difficulty of producing random numbers.  .

Comment: @rus9384 What do you mean by RNG?  The number of possible computer programs is countably infinite.

Comment: @DavidThornley, RNG is random number generator and it does not have to be computable. Therefore, a set of all RNGs is greater than the set of all computer programs.

Comment: @rus9384 I still don't know what you mean by "random number generator"  Is this supposed to be any sort of process that produces apparently random numbers?

Comment: @DavidThornley, you agree with me that TRNG produces unpredictable numbers. So, if we take a black box and see that any TM of the set of all TMs gives a prediction, it is not TRNG. Therefore, TRNG is not computable and there is no TM that can run an RNG procedure. And even more there is no such a procedure written on any TM language.

Comment: @rus9384 If I've properly understood, what you say means that it's impossible to _predict_ a random event with the procedure I described in my question. What I suppose with my 'list of all the possible rules/conditions' argument is that a random event is _logically impossible_

Comment: Well, it's not logically impossible. If the universe does not allow anything stronger than TM, yet there can be something random outside of our universe that affects it.

Comment: @rus9384 not sure that I got it. This something random outside our universe should be included in the list...

Comment: Not really. It might have no description in our universe even if it is infinite.

Comment: Random events are not only logically but even physically possible, and Geiger counters are used for truly random number generation in [HotBits](http://www.fourmilab.ch/hotbits/), for example. Things in mathematics do not have to be given by formulas or rules. "Random event...  cannot be causal" is false, quantum events are causal, you are confusing "causal" with "deterministic". "Possible conditions" (preconditions?) need not determine the outcome, and hence may not provide a deterministic rule.

Comment: @Conifold thank you for your notes, maybe my introduction about TRNG is confusing A quantum event is not deterministic – but it's statistic, not random. With a truly random event I can't have any hint of what will happen, like with an H/T toss of an ideal coin.

Comment: You do have a hint of what will happen, it's either heads or tails. Quantum double slit experiment is identical in this regard, one slit or the other. And there are standard ways of converting random variables with one distribution into ones with another by algebraic transformations, even if the probabilities weren't equal. So your random/statistical distinction is pointless even if it could be made, which it can't.

Comment: @Conifold You are right, I edited the question, maybe it could be useful for others. I was wondering: If I toss an ideal coin, I can't know if it will land on H or T. I consider it to be a random event, but it follows a rule: H or T, the odds are on par. This is the reason why the more tosses I do, the higher is the chance to get a similar number of T and H. But what if the odds themself could randomly change? i.e., for 1000 tosses the odds are better for H, from 1001 to 1328 to T and so on

Comment: Forget all that quantum qrap. The answer's that a truly random process wouldn't be describable by any computable function (hence, not "describable" at all).  Your so-called "list of all possible conditions" is just begging a diagonal argument refutation, which I'll let someone else construct in detail. The upshot is that if you're given an unending list of numbers generated by a truly random process, then no program, given input **i** can output the **i^th** number on the list. There are only a countably infinite number of programs, but an uncountably infinite number of **N-->N** functions.

Comment: @Conifold A claim that some kind of RNG is TRNG is unprovable. And unfalsifiable too.

Comment: @JohnForkosh, effectively what I meant.

Comment: There is no such thing as a random _event_. All randomness is in the _effects_. In probabilistic events the cause does not determine its effect with absolute accuracy, only the probability distribution where the effect lands _randomly_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A true random number is one that is unpredictable, even knowing the state of the Universe beforehand.  In the special case of a random series of numbers, each number has to be generated with probability independent of all the previous numbers.  It's not possible to do this with a mathematical formula or computer program, but it is possible to use principles of quantum mechanics (assuming they hold) to make a physical one.

Comment: Quantum TMs with unlimited memory are not more powerful than deterministic ones.

Comment: Why it is possible?

Comment: "A true random number is one that is unpredictable, even knowing the state of the Universe beforehand." -- Do you believe in such things? Isn't the randomness of QM part of an interpretation and not necessarily part of the theory itself? I don't know the answer, I'm wondering about that. A lot of people claim QM is a source of true randomness. How do you know?

Comment: Assuming that the principles of quantum mechanics actually hold is just as justifiable as assuming that pseudorandom number generators produce numbers indistinguishable to the modern observer from random numbers.

Comment: See use of https://www.nsandi.com/ernie for UK premium bonds so as to create random number for what is essentially a lottery.

Comment: 'Gargantuan chaotic gravitational three-body systems and their irreversibility to the Planck length' https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.04029

Comment: Any pseudo-random system given the same seed will produce the same outputs as another instance of the same system. Meanwhile, it's not hard at all to generate a system that generates randomness using the state of the universe, in such a way you can't predict its outcome for the simple reason there's not enough resources in the entire universe to do so; in particular observation of any part requires parts that influence the system and so need to be observed, necessitating more observing parts... and with this exponential growth you outgrow the observable universe long before knowing enough.

Answer (score 2):

> In mathematics, a true random number generator it's impossible, because any formula defines a process that, however complex, is not random.

A mathematician wouldn't use a formula to generate a random number. He or she would simply stipulate the properties that a random number might satisfy: for example, to model a dice, one would ask for a random integer drawn from the set {1,2,3,4,5,6} and uniformly distributed.

Nevertheless, what you say is accurate when it comes to actually implementing such a requirement on a computer. Then we have to be more precise and actually specify an algorithm.

> A random event must be unrelated to any cause or condition, and therefore cannot be causal. It is a brute fact par excellence.
>
> If I draw up a list of all the possible conditions, I can say that a random event is outside of it. But isn't this a rule that determines the conditions of a random event?

This is one extreme, the purely random; the other is purely deterministic. A proper typology of would explore the possibilities in between.

Answer (score 2):

Randomness is inversely proportional to the information you have. If you have right amount of information you can predict almost any thing. So if something is random then it is because your brain does not have enough information to predict the outcome.

Comment: I made some minor edits which you may roll back or continue editing. You can see the versions by clicking on the "edited" link. If you have references of others taking a similar view this would strengthen your answer. Welcome to this SE!

Comment: "Randomness is inversely proportional to the information you have." I think you mean percentage of information that I have compared to all information. Well, that's true. But there possibly are things which no brain can comprehend. Not even an infinite one.

Answer (score 0):

Statistical randomness is a mathematical property of a series. It means both the lack of any pattern and the unpredictability of the next item in the series.

Statistical randomness does not make any distinction between true and pseudo-randomness.

Philosophical (true) randomness is a property of a single item. It means that the item is not deliberately selected by anyone or a product of an algorithm (which has to be selected along with the seed values).

Truly random = Unintentional

Pseudo-random = Intentional

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the problem here, might be a conflicting ontology. True randomness can't be modelled, things that can't be modelled are considered not fully understood/understandable by physics.

The Many Worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics provides an interesting counterpoint. We do not find ourselves in the universe with a random outcome, but in every universe with every outcome. Determinism, and yet every version looking at every other, trying to work out why they are on this branch in particular.

Answer (score 0):

"In mathematics, a true random number generator it's impossible, because any formula defines a process that, however complex, is not random."

I'm going to point out that this question and its answer here suffer from a lack of any clear description of what constitutes a "random number generator" in mathematics, since "random number generator is not a technical term. But also, it has no obvious technical meaning.

The answer presented in this quote suggests that the random number generator is supposed to be defined by a formula. But what kinds of formulas count as formulas? This is left unstated, even though it would be possible to try to answer the question *only* if this is specified.

That addresses how to define what kinds of generators might or might not ever be random.

But also: *What does random mean here*? What is the criterion that a generator must satisfy in order to be classified as random? This, too, is not so easy to define. Suppose in the simplest case our random number generator started outputting a string of 0's and 1's, and the ideal case is the mythical fair coin flipped repeatedly in an unending sequence of (1/2,1/2) Bernoulli trials. Roughly speaking, the best definitions of a "random" sequence seem to require that for every natural number K, every string of 0's and 1's of length K occurs with the expected frequency 1/2^K.

The trouble is that to know this frequency, a) it is necessary to know an entire countable sequence of outputs, and b) for any finite initial string of outputs, that string can be ignored and the countable sequence will be just as random (or not) as it was with the finite initial string.

So for instance if for n = 1, 2, 3, ... we let the nth output of the generator be

F(n)  =  0 if p(n+1) = 1 (modulo 4),

F(n)  =  1 if p(n+1) = -1 (modulo 4)

(where p(n) denotes the nth prime number)

then this would probably satisfy my definition above.

*But that "generator" is entirely deterministic.*